# Cassandra daily data purge?

Tags: java, database, cassandra, hector

I have a column family inside cassandra which is used to store daily information. By being daily, I presume that it should be deleted every day.

So, I'd like to know, if is there possible to configure in cassandra a purge to these data.

I came here, because I havent found any deeper information about data purge in cassandra's page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Haven't used it yet, but Cassandra 0.7 has a TTL for columns. Maybe this will help you, it will basically delete the columns after a certain period of time has passed:

[datastax blog post about it](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-cassandra-07-expiring-columns)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but for any Googlers who come along wanting an answer for versions 2.x+, here is the DataStax doc on [Determining Time To Live](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_ttl_t.html) (TTL).  Using CQL with the `excelsior` keyspace and the `clicks` column family, you create your table as usual:

```
CREATE TABLE excelsior.clicks (
  userid uuid,
  url text,
  name text,
  PRIMARY KEY (userid, url)
);
```

When you insert your data, you specify the `USING TTL` clause, followed by the number of seconds that the data should persist for:

```
INSERT INTO excelsior.clicks (
  userid, url, name)
  VALUES (
    3715e600-2eb0-11e2-81c1-0800200c9a66,
    'http://apache.org',
    'Mary')
    USING TTL 86400;
```

Note that 86400 is the number of seconds in a day.  You can also set the TTL with a [prepared statement](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/quick_start/qsSimpleClientBoundStatements_t.html) in the Java CQL Driver, simply by treating it like any other bound parameter:

```
String strCQL = "INSERT INTO excelsior.clicks (userid, url, name) "
    + "VALUES (?,?,?) USING TTL ? ";
boundStatement = new BoundStatement(statement);
mySession.execute(boundStatement.bind(
  UUID.fromString("3715e600-2eb0-11e2-81c1-0800200c9a66"),
  "http://apache.org",
  "Mary",
  86400) );
```